# Finding duplicates from a column in a table based on id, how much they did a transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find duplicates from a column in a table based on user_id how much they did a transaction based on borrow_id

So the table looks like:

```
borrow_progress
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
|user_id | borrow_id |  state     |  remark    | 
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
|  170   |  236      |  10        |  waiting   |    
|  170   |  236      |  22        |  proceed   |      
|  170   |  236      |  26        |  success   |     
|  170   |  236      |  30        |  sent      |    
|  172   |  237      |  10        |  waiting   |   
|  172   |  237      |  22        |  proceed   | 
|  172   |  237      |  90        |  fail      |
|  170   |  238      |  10        |  waiting   | 
|  170   |  238      |  22        |  proceed   | 
|  170   |  238      |  90        |  fail      | 
|  173   |  239      |  10        |  waiting   | 
|  173   |  239      |  22        |  proceed   | 
|  173   |  239      |  26        |  success   |
|  170   |  240      |  10        |  waiting   |   
| ...    | ...       |  ...       |  ...       |  
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

---

My expected outputs are:

1.

```
+--------+------------------+
|user_id | count(borrow_id) |
+--------+------------------+
|  170   |         3        |       
|  172   |         1        |      
|  173   |         1        |     
+--------+------------------+
```

2.

```
+--------+------------------+
|user_id |        borrow_id |
+--------+------------------+
|  170   |         236      |
|  170   |         238      |
|  170   |         240      |       
|  172   |         237      |      
|  173   |         239      |     
+--------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `DISTINCT` here, for both queries:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT borrow_id) AS cnt
FROM borrow_progress
GROUP BY
    user_id
ORDER BY
    user_id;
```

And:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    user_id,
    borrow_id
FROM borrow_progress
ORDER BY
    user_id,
    borrow_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather these are the two queries

```
select user_id, count(distinct borrow_id ) 
from borrow_progress
group by user_id


select user_id,  borrow_id
from borrow_progress
group by user_id,  borrow_id
```